# Add a Appendix page before the appendices appear

Tags: chapters, appendices

Hi I'm using the code of this post [Insert page before each chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183584/insert-page-before-each-chapter) to generate a chapters pages with shape before each chapter begins, but with now I want to say appendix when the appendix section begins, not for each appendix chapter.

```
\usepackage{xparse, adforn}
\let\origchapter\chapter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapter{s o m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\def\myshortchtitle{#3}}{\def\myshortchtitle{#2}}%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vspace*{.25\textheight}%
  {\centering
  \stepcounter{chapter}%
  \LARGE\bfseries
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \phantom{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}{%
    \chaptername\ \thechapter}\par
  \vskip .025\textheight
  \Huge #3\par
  \adforn{22}\adforn{50}\par}
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
  \clearpage
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \origchapter*{#3}}{%
    \origchapter[\myshortchtitle]{#3}}}
```

Comment: Instead of `\chaptername`, you can (should) use `\@chapapp` (requires you to wrap the redefinition with a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair. Do you want to have written `Appendix` *only*, or `Appendix X Appendix Title`?

Comment: Thanks this give me an approach but I want only one page for Appendix for the appendix section not one for each appendix, I edit question for better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the following would suffice in order to get what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xparse,adforn,lipsum}
\let\origchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapter{s o m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\def\myshortchtitle{#3}}{\def\myshortchtitle{#2}}%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vspace*{.25\textheight}%
  {\centering
  \stepcounter{chapter}%
  \LARGE\bfseries
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \phantom{\@chapapp\ \thechapter}}{%
    \@chapapp\ \thechapter}\par
  \vskip .025\textheight
  \Huge #3\par
  \adforn{22}\adforn{50}\par}
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
  \clearpage
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \origchapter*{#3}}{%
    \origchapter[\myshortchtitle]{#3}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\appendix
{\RenewDocumentCommand{\origchapter}{s o m}{}
 \chapter*{Appendices}}
\let\chapter\origchapter

\chapter{An appendix}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Another appendix}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I've temporarily disabled the regular `\chapter`-like construction, only for placing the "chapter page". Subsequently I remove the "chapter page" `\chapter` by reverting back to `\origchapter`.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the appendix package it is easy. 
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
Here, page option puts the extra page before starting the appendices.