# Title pages for chapters and chapter thumbs

Tags: chapters, chapterthumb

I am trying to generate a report document, where I would like to add a separate chapter title page as shown by CFR https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183613/45116.

Her code works for me, but I am facing some troubles since I have chapterthumbs. The trouble is that on Chapter title page I am getting chapterthumb with wrong chapter number. Ex. On title page of chapter 1, chapterthumb is showing chapter 0.

I will be okay with any of one following scenario:
1. Removing chapterthumb from (only) chapter title page
OR
2. Having correct chapterthumb on chapter title page

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperheight=24cm,paperwidth=17cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Adding box to the chapter
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}
\definecolor{chapterthumbbg}{HTML}{6F7170}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \ifshowchapterthumb\ifodd\value{page}
      \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{\baselineskip}%
          \colorbox{chapterthumbbg}{\textcolor{white}{\begin{turn}{0}\textbf{{\LARGE \thechapter}}\end{turn}}}%
        }%
      }%
    \else\fi\fi
  }
}


\newif\ifshowchapterthumb

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{Eq. \arabic{equation}}



%%
\usepackage{xparse, adforn}
\let\origchapter\chapter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapter{s o m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\def\myshortchtitle{#3}}{\def\myshortchtitle{#2}}%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vspace*{.25\textheight}%
  {\centering
  \stepcounter{chapter}%
  \LARGE\bfseries
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \phantom{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}{%
    \chaptername\ \thechapter}\par
  \vskip .025\textheight
  \Huge #3\par
  \adforn{22}\adforn{50}\par}
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
  \clearpage
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \origchapter*{#3}}{%
    \origchapter[\myshortchtitle]{#3}}}
%%

\begin{document}


%\showchapterthumbfalse
%
%\input{Frontmatter/Title}
%\pagebreak
%\input{Frontmatter/committe}
%\pagebreak
%\input{Frontmatter/official_title}
%\pagebreak
%\input{Frontmatter/approvedby}
%\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\mbox{}

\let\oldchapter\chapter% if you don't want the ToC to have a page before it
\let\chapter\origchapter% if you don't want the ToC to have a page before it
\tableofcontents
\let\chapter\oldchapter% if you don't want the ToC to have a page before it


%\newpage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\mbox{}

\part{Name 1}

\showchapterthumbtrue
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-27]

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\showchapterthumbfalse
\showchapterthumbtrue
\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]
\showchapterthumbfalse

\part{Name 2}
\showchapterthumbtrue
\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]
\showchapterthumbfalse

%\include{Mainmatter/Chapter_1}
%%\newpage
%%\thispagestyle{empty}
%%\mbox{}
%\include{Mainmatter/Chapter_2}
%%\newpage
%%\thispagestyle{empty}
%%\mbox{}
%
%\part{Name}
%\include{Mainmatter/Chapter_3}



\end{document}
```

Some help on this issue will be highly appreciated. :)
Thanks in advance.